# Why is running code single time slower than running four times in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, benchmarking

See code and benchmark here: http://jsperf.com/single-vs-multiple-times-2

I am seeing a strange behaviour in javascript. Running code single time is taking twice as much as running it multiple times. Following is the code:

**Preparation code**

```
var MakeKeyCodepoint = function() {};
MakeKeyCodepoint.prototype.makeKey = function(word) {
  var len = word.length;
  if (len > 255) {
    return undefined;
  }
  var i = len >> 2;
  return String.fromCharCode(
    (word.charCodeAt(0) & 0x03) << 14 |
    (word.charCodeAt(i) & 0x03) << 12 |
    (word.charCodeAt(i + i) & 0x03) << 10 |
    (word.charCodeAt(i + i + i) & 0x03) << 8 |
    len
  );
};
var makeKeyCodepointObj = new MakeKeyCodepoint();
```

**Running single time**

```
var key = makeKeyCodepointObj.makeKey('www.wired.com');
```

**Running four times**

```
var key = makeKeyCodepointObj.makeKey('www.wired.com');
key = makeKeyCodepointObj.makeKey('www.youtube.com');
key = makeKeyCodepointObj.makeKey('scorecardresearch.com');
key = makeKeyCodepointObj.makeKey('www.google-analytics.com');
```

I am running it in chrome 34 in osx.

Comment: I the same result as OP

Comment: I'm not questioning _whether_ the result is as described - I'm asking to see it @JonasGrumann . Are the results being misread/misinterpreted? I see the difference as at most 1% ops/s, the browserscope summary show the opposite trend to the question.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are benchmarking the operations per second, not the time for completion.
running it more times at onces would have more operations to perform so your results seem reasonable

reviewing the revisions i would say that was an anomaly run and the result was likely longer due to website server response when you ran it

[Revision 4](http://jsperf.com/single-vs-multiple-times-2/4) shows what i would expect to see

Comment: I don't think so. It is the time for completion of all operation in group rather than one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your benchmark so that it actually does something: http://jsperf.com/single-vs-multiple-times-2/5

Should give exactly 4 times slower.